# Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature Android Studio 3.1 Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Hello I'm getting error when I want to Run App :
error :

C:\Users...\AndroidStudioProjects\projects\HelloWorld\app\src\main\java\training\androidkotlin\helloworld\MainActivity.kt: (8, 5): Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V):
    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Unit defined in training.androidkotlin.helloworld.MainActivity
    fun onCreate(p0: Bundle?): Unit defined in training.androidkotlin.helloworld.MainActivity

Code :

```
    package training.androidkotlin.helloworld

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Override
    protected fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

How to solve it please ?
Thanks

Comment: Change your parameter type to  to `Bundle?` because the bundle can be null in Java.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answre, please I'm new in Android Studio, can you tell me How to change it ?
Best regards

Comment: Just change it to `protected fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`

Comment: Thank you for your answere, I did it But nothing, when try to have more details I got it : Line 3 in MainActivity .kt suspend : thread

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin `@Override` is a keyword, so change `@Override fun xx` to `override fun xx` and it will fix the issue.

Comment: You might have a typo. You wrote overload instead of override the last two times

Comment: Not so much a typo as brain crosstalk, since `@Override` is the method `overloading` annotation :P

Answer (score -1):

Thank you so much for all you proposition, I fixed the problem.
1. I try to reinstall Android Studion in case if there was sone failure during the installation and I change my code like this :

```
package training.androidkotlin.helloworld

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Override
    protected override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

One more time thank you for every one who took his time to give me their answers.
Cheers !